# Twitter card image not working despite meta tags

Tags: html, image, twitter, meta-tags, twitter-card

I'm trying to set up a Twitter card for a website. I've the following meta tags:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="My Title">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="My description">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="img/foo.png">
```

All seems fine. Strangely enough, the [Twitter's card validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) does not display the image. I've just read a lot of posts about this kind of issue but none of them worked for my case.

It seems that also LinkedIn sharings do have the same no-image problem.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I fixed with the complete URL of the image:

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://bar/img/foo.png">
```